# Post a video with multipart in java

Tags: java, http, post

I am trying to upload a video with java to an api of Microsoft(Video Indexer API) using a request Http Post and it's work with Postman

But when i do this in java it's not work

This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    try
    {

        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://videobreakdown.azure-api.net/Breakdowns/Api/Partner/Breakdowns?name=film2&privacy=Public");

        URI uri = builder.build();


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        httpPost.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "19b9d647b7e649b38ec9dbb472b6d668");

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipart = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        File f = new File("src/main/resources/film2.mov");
        multipart.addBinaryBody("film2",new FileInputStream(f));

        HttpEntity entityMultipart = multipart.build();

        httpPost.setEntity(entityMultipart);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null)
        {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
    }
```

And this is the error:

```
{"ErrorType":"INVALID_INPUT","Message":"Content is not multipart."}
```

And for Postman this is a screen for all the parameter that i have to put on the Http Request

[Screen for all the params on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8BFi.png)

And for the header:

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNlQH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem

It was this line : httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

I don't have to write that the Content-Type is multipart if I use a MultipartEntityBuilder ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution definitely works
When you are using Postman for multipart request then don't specify a custom Content-Type in Header. So your Header tab in Postman should be empty. Postman will determine form-data boundary. In Body tab of Postman you should select form-data and select file type.